# How can I write a SQL-request to reverse field values?

Tags: sql, db2

For given CTE reverse field values as shown in table.
`

```
with
cal(ID,NAME,LVL1,LVL2,LVL3,LVL4,LVL5,LVL6,LVL7) as (values 
(1,'aaa','rt','fg','as','df',null,null,null),
(2,'bbb','yt','zx',null,null,null,null,null))
```

`
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnK74.jpg)

My request but it dosen't work

```
with a(ID, ColX, ColY, ColZ) as (values (0, '001', '010', 100), (1, '002', '020', 200), (2, '003', '030', 300))
SELECT ID, ColX, ColY, ColZ
FROM a CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAX(ID) AS max_id FROM a) m
ORDER BY ID
```

The result should be like this (It is the CTE to show the table I need)

```
with
cal(ID,NAME,LVL1,LVL2,LVL3,LVL4,LVL5,LVL6,LVL7) as (values 
(1,'aaa','df','as','fg','rt',null,null,null),
(2,'bbb','zx','yt',null,null,null,null,null))
```

Comment: Plrase, provide the desired result set in a table form (as text, don't post pictures) for given base data expressed by this CTE.

Comment: Mark Barinstein, I corrected the question

Comment: So, CTE `a` is a source, `cal` is a target, right? If yes, then what's the description of the transformation algorithm?

Comment: Ohh, my bad, the example of my request is an attempt to reverse values. 
But it dosen't work. I shouldn't show the example of this request cause it confused. 
So what I don't understand. 
I have sql-request (the first), after this I should manipulate to reverse values. And i should get table like the last sql-request.

Comment: Why aren't null values "reversed"? What if they would mix with not null values, and not just follow them as in the example?

Comment: Idk((, just I have this task. 
I'm trying to solve this problem during 3 days.

Comment: You must describe the exact transformation rules, if you have other rows having different content. If you have just these ones with these constants, then it's simple: just construct correct expressions for each column based on the row id.

Comment: I have only those rows. 
I used UPDATE to replace the value, but it dosen't work. 
```with a(ID, NAME, LVL1, LVL2, LVL3, LVL4, LVL5, LVL6, LVL7) as (values (1,'aaa','rt','fg','as','df',null,null,null), (2,'bbb','yt','zx',null,null,null,null,null)) UPDATE a SET LVL4 = 'tg' WHERE ID = 1```
How can I replace the value by ID and name of column?

Comment: Did I get you right, that you have a table with these 2 rows, what you provide with your CTE is just to display the content of this table, and you need to update this table to get the desired result? If yes, then is [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/v03DnC4S) what you need?